# Can't install Freya on SSD NVMe + Nvidia Optimus

Tags: release-freya, system-installation, nvidia, ssd

I just get a new laptop and I can't manage to install Elementary Freya on it.
Live CD doesn't launch, same for the install process, all I get is some Kernel lines and the process stopped.Ubuntu 16.04 beta get until the live session (only with the option 'AHCI disable' otherwise, same things, kernel lines and process stopped..)

I have a SSD Samsung M.2 NVMe, and an i7 Skylake + Geforce GTX 950m. Windows 7 is already installed, I want to do a dual boot.

I've check and some people can get through the install procedure by disable the discrete GPU from the BIOS, but I don't have the option on mine (ridiculous...).

I was thinking maybe recompiling the ISO of Freya with the last linux 4.5 Kernel (because the live cd of Ubuntu 16.04 is running), but I have absolutely no idea how I can do that..

Any ideas ?

MAny thanks !

Comment: What PC is this. Ubuntu 16.04 uses kernel 4.4

Comment: Can you add a photo

Comment: it's this one : https://www.pcspecialist.co.uk/notebooks/SkyFireV-14/

Comment: It's working on live cd with the 4.4 kernel of Ubuntu 16.04, but as far as I reckon, there are been some improvement with the nvidia optimus technology with the last 4.5 kernel. That's why I was thinking recompiling Freya with the 4.5 kernel already on the ISO..

Comment: Have you tried to boot with "nouveau.modeset=0" grub option?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks !

I manage to install Freya, install the latest Nvidia Drivers  for the kernel 3.19 BUT impossible to update to kernel 4.2, 4.4 and 4.5, just got black screen..
I tried to add nouveau.modeset=0  or nvidia.modeset=0 , nomodeset even modprobe.blacklist=nouveau

On Ubuntu 16.04 beta with the kernel 4.4.0.15 and acpi=off, I can go to the live CD, no boot from Freya with 4.4.

The wifi is not working either, the card is not recognized, I guess it's fixed with the 4.4 kernel.

I'm quite running out of option here

EDIT - same result with Nvidia Drivers 364 removed and nouveau.modeset=0

Answer (score 1):

when i was trying to solve a problem i got a problem similar than yours, i had problems installing 4.5 kernel, if you can't do it from freya, download kernel and nvidia linux driver from windows and put them in a pendrive

Step 1 Download and install Kernel 4.0 Packages from

http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.0-vivid/

In my case for x64

linux-headers-4.0.0-040000-generic_4.0.0-040000.201504121935_amd64.deb
linux-headers-4.0.0-040000_4.0.0-040000.201504121935_all.deb
linux-image-4.0.0-040000-generic_4.0.0-040000.201504121935_amd64.deb

and install the new kernel

sudo dpkg -i linux-headers-4.*.deb linux-image-4.*.deb

And Nvidia last drivers from it official website (you will download as a script i think, so you will have to give it execute permissions with chmod +x)

http://www.nvidia.es/Download/index.aspx?lang=es

If elementary doesn't start, enter in the recovery mode and then in root console, you will need reading and writing permissions

mount -o remount,rw /

then install first the kernel 4.0 and reboot and then enter in recovery mode for the kernel 4.0 --> consola as root and uninstall all drivers

apt-get remove --purge nvidia*
apt-get remove --purge xserver-xorg-video-nouveau*

and install the executable file that you downloaded from nvidia offical website

./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-361.42.run  (in my case)

This way now i can access to TTY console, see the elementary logo and Graphical environtment in full resolution.

Comment: thanks for the reply :)

After 3 days fighting with Freya, I gave up an install Xubuntu 16.04, put the 4.5 kernel, blacklist the nouveau drivers, install bbswitch-dkms, add bbswitch to /etc/modules-load.d and turn off power to the nVidia GPU using: sudo tee /proc/acpi/bbswitch <<<OFF
Just using the nvidia card on windows for gaming

Comment: and I tweak Xubuntu with Plank and install pantheon-files, waiting for Loki to be released..!

Answer (score 0):

I've got an MSI laptop same specs. and I'm having no end of issues installing Ubuntu. Same problems with the live CD. I did manage to get 16.04 installed but on reboot all I got was a desktop background and that's it, Unity didn't finish loading.

Other than waiting for firmware updates and Ubuntu 16.10, I don't know what else to do. I will use windows 10 as a last resort but I really don't want to use windows so any help would be really appreciated.